# QuickFixN resent message is different

Tags: quickfix, quickfixn

I'm receiving (and sending) a ResendRequest after a login where a gap in the sequence numbers show that there are missing messages. The counterparty's ResendRequest asks for my messages from seqNo 2830, which my QuickFixN engine supplies, however the 2830 message seems to have changed - previously it was a Logout message, now it is a SequenceReset message.

Is this right? If so why? If not, what could be going on?

Logs:

> 20150810-20:59:02.594 : 8=FIX.4.29=7235=034=312149=COUNTERPARTY56=ME57=ADMIN52=20150810-20:58:59.48410=040
>   20150810-20:59:24.605 : 8=FIX.4.29=6335=034=282949=ME52=20150810-20:59:24.60556=COUNTERPARTY10=023
>   20150810-20:59:32.596 : 8=FIX.4.29=7235=034=312249=COUNTERPARTY56=ME57=ADMIN52=20150810-20:59:29.48410=039
>   20150810-20:59:46.697 : 8=FIX.4.29=9635=534=312349=COUNTERPARTY56=ME57=ADMIN52=20150810-20:59:43.58558=Closing Connection!!10=029
>   20150810-20:59:46.698 : 8=FIX.4.29=6335=534=283049=ME52=20150810-20:59:46.69856=COUNTERPARTY10=036
>   20150810-21:02:17.495 : 8=FIX.4.29=7535=A34=283149=ME52=20150810-21:02:17.49556=COUNTERPARTY98=0108=3010=059
>   20150810-21:02:17.567 : 8=FIX.4.29=8435=A34=320549=COUNTERPARTY56=ME57=ADMIN52=20150810-21:02:14.45098=0108=3010=062
>   20150810-21:02:17.570 : 8=FIX.4.29=7535=234=283249=ME52=20150810-21:02:17.56956=COUNTERPARTY7=312416=010=042
>   20150810-21:02:17.642 : 8=FIX.4.29=8435=234=320649=COUNTERPARTY56=ME57=ADMIN52=20150810-21:02:14.4507=283016=010=046
>   20150810-21:02:17.648 : 8=FIX.4.29=10835=434=283043=Y49=ME52=20150810-21:02:17.64856=COUNTERPARTY122=20150810-21:02:17.64736=2833123=Y10=228
>   20150810-21:02:17.655 : 8=FIX.4.29=21635=934=312443=Y49=COUNTERPARTY56=ME128=ME122=20150810-21:00:50.92252=20150810-21:02:14.52511=2c14R3A-001-01-0000337=B2c14R3A-001-01-00003ME58=EO_FAIL102=041=2-14R3A-001-01-0000339=8434=110=017
>   20150810-21:02:17.655 : 8=FIX.4.29=21635=934=312543=Y49=COUNTERPARTY56=ME128=ME122=20150810-21:00:50.92252=20150810-21:02:14.52611=2c14R3A-003-01-0000337=B2c14R3A-003-01-00003ME58=EO_FAIL102=041=2-14R3A-003-01-0000339=8434=110=025
>   20150810-21:02:17.655 : 8=FIX.4.29=21635=934=312643=Y49=COUNTERPARTY56=ME128=ME122=20150810-21:00:50.92352=20150810-21:02:14.52611=2c14R3A-004-01-0000337=B2c14R3A-004-01-00003ME58=EO_FAIL102=041=2-14R3A-004-01-0000339=8434=110=030
>   20150810-21:02:17.655 : 8=FIX.4.29=21635=934=312743=Y49=COUNTERPARTY56=ME128=ME122=20150810-21:00:50.92352=20150810-21:02:14.52611=2c14R3A-005-01-0000N37=B2c14R3A-005-01-0000NME58=EO_FAIL102=041=2-14R3A-005-01-0000N39=8434=110=115

Comment: Could you post the logs with a printable delimiter (e.g., '^' or '|')? The SOH character that delimits tag/value pairs does not print, so the messages you posted are not easily readable.